# removing buttons with removeFromSuperview

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I try to remove the buttons in one of my view controllers, somehow this results in a crash.
The code below actually executes and also the number of buttons is correct. For safety reasons I added the check if it is a UIButton class, although not needed.
At the end of my function viewWillDisappear this crashes.
So what do I forget ?

```
for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
NSLog(@"subviews Count=%d",[[self.view subviews]count]);

if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
           [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: I can't see any problem with the above code, If you have correctly added buttons as subview. Probably there is memory corruption some where else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks ok.  One common error to watch out for is creating a UIButton like this

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonOfType: some_type];  // note: no alloc
```

and then releasing this when it has not been retained (and therefore doesn't need to be released).

Also, why are removing buttons from a view when that view is about to disappear?

Please post more info about your crash - what does the log say?

Comment: I use retain when creating the UIButton

Comment: Rayfleck, thanks for pointing me in the good direction. I was really convinced that it was alloced, but it was not. Somewhere I did implent a release.